# HBase Snappy Compression - Failed to Create Table, CompressionTest Succeeded

Tags: hadoop, compression, hbase, snappy

I have been trying to resolve a wired issue of HBase related to Snappy Compression. Following is the detailed description of everything related to this issue:

1. Issue description:
   When I tried to create a table with Snappy compression in HBase shell: (See attachment for detailed HBase shell log in debug mode)

hbase(main):001:0> create 't3', { NAME => 'cf1', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY' }

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/local/solono/package/local_1/Linux-2.6c2.5-x86_64/Hadoop/Hadoop-2140.0-0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/local/solono/package/local_1/Linux-2.6c2.5-x86_64/Slf4j-log4j12/Slf4j-log4j12-37.0-0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]

    ERROR: java.io.IOException: Compression algorithm 'snappy' previously failed test.
                    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CompressionTest.testCompression(CompressionTest.java:85)
                    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkCompression(HMaster.java:1772)
                    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkCompression(HMaster.java:1765)
                    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1747)
                    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:1782)
                    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java:40470)
                    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2012)
                    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:98)
                    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.FifoRpcScheduler$1.run(FifoRpcScheduler.java:73)
                    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

2. CompressionTest result:
   When I run the compression test, it succeeded:

```
[kalidasyan@TestCluster-hbase-linux-host]/solono/env/TestClusterHBase% ./bin/solono-hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CompressionTest hdfs://TestCluster-hadoop-nn2.aka.iad.TestCluster.com:9000/user/kalidasyan/hbase/impressions/00/part-m-00074.gz snappy

    /solono/env/TestClusterHBase/bin/hbase-config.sh: line 43: cd: ../../../package/local_1/Linux-2.6c2.5-x86_64/Hbase/Hbase-521.0-0/bin: No such file or directory
    2015-10-02 21:36:12,266 INFO  [main] Configuration.deprecation: hadoop.native.lib is deprecated. Instead, use io.native.lib.available
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/local/solono/package/local_1/Linux-2.6c2.5-x86_64/Hadoop/Hadoop-2140.0-0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/local/solono/package/local_1/Linux-2.6c2.5-x86_64/Slf4j-log4j12/Slf4j-log4j12-37.0-0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
    2015-10-02 21:36:13,043 INFO  [main] util.ChecksumType: Checksum using org.apache.hadoop.util.PureJavaCrc32
    2015-10-02 21:36:13,044 INFO  [main] util.ChecksumType: Checksum can use org.apache.hadoop.util.PureJavaCrc32C
    2015-10-02 21:36:13,236 INFO  [main] compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.snappy]
    2015-10-02 21:36:13,242 INFO  [main] compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor [.snappy]
    2015-10-02 21:36:13,457 INFO  [main] compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.snappy]
    SUCCESS
```

3. Native library check result:
   When I run the hadoop native library check for HBase:

```
    
[kalidasyan@TestCluster-hbase-linux-host]/solono/env/TestClusterHBase% ./bin/solono-hbase --config ./var/hbase-config org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeLibraryChecker

/solono/env/TestClusterHBase/bin/hbase-config.sh: line 43: cd: ../../../package/local_1/Linux-2.6c2.5-x86_64/Hbase/Hbase-521.0-0/bin: No such file or directory

2015-10-04 23:44:09,747 WARN  [main] bzip2.Bzip2Factory: Failed to load/initialize native-bzip2 library system-native, will use pure-Java version
2015-10-04 23:44:09,750 INFO  [main] zlib.ZlibFactory: Successfully loaded & initialized native-zlib library
Native library checking:
hadoop:  true /local/solono/package/local_1/Linux-2.6c2.5-x86_64/Hadoop/Hadoop-2140.0-0/lib/libhadoop.so
zlib:    true /lib64/libz.so.1
snappy:  true /solono/env/TestClusterHBase/lib/libsnappy.so.1
lz4:     true revision:99
bzip2:   false 
openssl: true /solono/env/TestClusterHBase/lib/libcrypto.so
```

I set the following HBase-site.xml property, and both HMaster and RegionServer are able to start and work properly.

```
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.codecs</name>
    <value>snappy</value>
  </property>
```

4. The HBase shell process in any of the HBase hosts:

```
    kalidasyan     6942  0.7  0.6 10373900 775808 pts/0 Sl+  21:32   0:15 /solono/env/TestClusterHBase/jdk/bin/java -Dproc_shell -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p -Xmx8192m -Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=600 -Dsun.net.inetaddr.negative.ttl=300 -Dsolono.appgroup=productAds -Dorg.mortbay.util.FileResource.checkAliases=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/solono/env/TestClusterHBase/var/output/logsheapdump.hprof -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Dhbase.ruby.sources=/solono/env/TestClusterHBase/lib/ruby -Dhbase.log.dir=/solono/env/TestClusterHBase/var/output/logs -Dhbase.log.file=hbase.log -Dhbase.home.dir=/solono/env/TestClusterHBase -Dhbase.id.str= -Dhbase.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/solono/env/TestClusterHBase/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64 -Dhbase.security.logger=INFO,NullAppender org.jruby.Main -X+O /solono/env/TestClusterHBase/bin/hirb.rb
```

We can see the property

```
"java.library.path=/solono/env/TestClusterHBase/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64"
```

from the process parameter.

And "ls -l /solono/env/TestClusterHBase/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64" shows:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 92 Oct  2 21:26 libhadoopsnappy.la -> /solono/_env/TestClusterHBase-swit1na.7444503.167194907.744537033/lib/libhadoopsnappy.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 92 Oct  2 21:26 libhadoopsnappy.so -> /solono/_env/TestClusterHBase-swit1na.7444503.167194907.744537033/lib/libhadoopsnappy.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 94 Oct  2 21:26 libhadoopsnappy.so.0 -> /solono/_env/TestClusterHBase-swit1na.7444503.167194907.744537033/lib/libhadoopsnappy.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 98 Oct  2 21:26 libhadoopsnappy.so.0.0.1 -> /solono/_env/TestClusterHBase-swit1na.7444503.167194907.744537033/lib/libhadoopsnappy.so.0.0.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 86 Oct  2 21:26 libhadoop.so -> /solono/_env/TestClusterHBase-swit1na.7444503.167194907.744537033/lib/libhadoop.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 92 Oct  2 21:26 libhadoop.so.1.0.0 -> /solono/_env/TestClusterHBase-swit1na.7444503.167194907.744537033/lib/libhadoop.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 86 Oct  2 21:26 libsnappy.la -> /solono/_env/TestClusterHBase-swit1na.7444503.167194907.744537033/lib/libsnappy.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 86 Oct  2 21:26 libsnappy.so -> /solono/_env/TestClusterHBase-swit1na.7444503.167194907.744537033/lib/libsnappy.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 88 Oct  2 21:26 libsnappy.so.1 -> /solono/_env/TestClusterHBase-swit1na.7444503.167194907.744537033/lib/libsnappy.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 92 Oct  2 21:26 libsnappy.so.1.1.4 -> /solono/_env/TestClusterHBase-swit1na.7444503.167194907.744537033/lib/libsnappy.so.1.1.4
```

Could anybody please help with this issue?  Any suggestion or clue will be very much appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snappy does not work on RHEL Operating System as it depends on other libraries (Clib) which are not present on RHEL, it works with latest linux OS.